# Swagger/OpenAPI annotations V3 - use Enum values in swagger annotations

Tags: java, enums, annotations, swagger, openapi

I'm creating the the API description of our application using Swagger/OpenApi V3 annotations, imported from following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.45</version>
</dependency>
```

One of the annotations is a `@Schema` annotation that accepts an attribute named `allowableValues` which allows a an array of strings:

```
@Schema(description = "example", 
        allowableValues = {"exampleV1", "exampleV2"}, 
        example = "exampleV1", required = true)
private String example;
```

Now I would like to use a custom method constructed on our Enum class that returns the allowable strings array, so it does not needs to be added upon each time we add a type to our Enum. So that we can use it like this:

```
public enum ExampleEnum {
    EXAMPLEV1, EXAMPLEV2;
    public static String[] getValues() {...}
}

@Schema(description = "example", 
        allowableValues = ExampleEnum.getValues(), 
        example = "exampleV1", required = true)
private String example;
```

Now this doesn't compile because the method is not known when executing the annotation.
Is there such a solution that allows usage of Enums in the swagger V3 annotation attributes values?

Had a look in following resources:

- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/

> You can define reusable enums in the global components section and reference them via $ref elsewhere.

Worst case I can indeed have it defined in one constant place and after adding a type to the Enum only have one other place needed to add the type to. But I first want to explore the above mentioned solution if it's possible.

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#schema

Doesn't say anything about using any classes or dynamic generated values.

- [Enum in swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936140/enum-in-swagger)

Is about documenting enums in swagger and not using them in the swagger annotations API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try using `@Schema(implementation = ExampleEnum.class, ...)`, you can add all other properties you want. I would need more info on your implementation but try this first.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the code anymore so I cannot try it out anymore... Anybody else can confirm this?

Comment: this does not seem to work for me as I add @Schema(implementation = MyEnum.class) to one of the parameters in a controller.

Comment: @ojathelonius Please share your code and more context for your issue

Comment: I confirm it works well, at least on **OpenAPI v2**, just verified in several places of my code and this helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: For anybody trying to get this working with an array: 
use @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = ExampleEnum.class)) instead!

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I have added an annotation in my enum:

```java
@Schema(enumAsRef = true)
public enum WikipediaLanguage {
  ...
}
```

and then just used it annotated as a Parameter in the argument of they REST controller method:

```java
@Parameter(
    description = "Language of the Wikipedia in use",
    required = true
) @RequestParam WikipediaLanguage lang
```